# API for checking manufacturability of 3D models

Tags: 3d-models, print-api

I am wondering if there is an API that can check for some basic (hopefully configurable) design rules such as manifolds, hanging edges, overhang lengths etc. for a given 3D model (say, in STL format).

I am looking for such an API to create a score for a number of 3D models for research purposes.

Comment: You could probably get pretty far just slicing them from the command line with Cura or another slicer and extracting the comments for overhangs, bridges, etc. with appropriate settings to detect them.

Comment: I see, thanks. Does Cura have an API that I can call in my code?

Comment: Cura engine source code should be up somewhere so yes...